# WC Composite product add more products of a component in defined number of steps

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

As you will find out, I'm a designer with little experience coding. I´ve been trying to get the quantities of an specific component to be multiplied by 3 for a 3 month subscription plan (each month clients get 1 item, so any end quantity has to be a multiple of 3). I´ve tried the following snippet but I get an NaN error (Not a Number):

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'woocommerce_composited_product_quantity', 'input_multiply_component', 10, 7);
function input_multiply_component($args, $default_quantity, $quantity_min, $product, $component_id, $composite_product, $component_data) {
    $variable_id = 1564249024;
    if($component_data->get_component_id()==$variable_id) {
        $quantity_min = 3;
    }
    $args['min_value'] = $quantity_min;
    $args['step'] = $quantity_min;
    return $args;
}
```

Update I started out from the following lines of code and I don´t know if I got the arguments wrong and somehow also returning an array:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_composited_product_quantity', 'input_multiply_component', 10, 6 );

function input_multiply_component( $default_quantity, $quantity_min, $quantity_max, $product, $component_id, $composite_product ) {
    return 2;
}
```

Comment: Whats the error?

Comment: I get a NaN error. I will update the question with the code I started with, just in case it may have some clues.